# Relative URL in backbone model , to a port different form that in browser url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am doing a project in javascript and use backbonejs for structuring. While using relative path in backbone model, the request is send to host:port used in browser url by default (here http://localhost:9090) . But I need to send request to my application server with port localhost:8080 . We can't use same port for client and server. So how can we handle this?

I have a json in client side specifying the root url:

**data.json**

`{data:[{"urlRoot": "http:localhost:8080"}]}`

Comment: Assuming your endpoint supports [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) you can just provide full URL in the model. If not you need to enable it in the backend resorce

Comment: I don't want the full URL in the model. How to enable it in the backend source? Can you explain or provide some link .

Comment: Use  $.ajaxPrefilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use model urlRoot http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot

Or do specifically set http://localhost:8080/  as root in your model url (no relative path so you should keep this root information in some conf module so you can change it easily for all model when going into production).

You could also store the root url in model prototype instead of conf module

Comment: Can you explain or provide some link to clarify the 2 (with conf module)and 3rd point(with model prototype). I need not want to hardcode the  http://localhost:8080/  in my code.

Comment: You can write a module which contains your url for all the model, are you using requirejs for example ? Also since you want to call a server which has not served your page you will have at some point to write the url somewhere, in a configuration file or in backbone.model.prototype